# how to add subtle transiton between images?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066119/how-to-transition-between-images-in-a-slider/50067270#50067270) question and was able to get my slider to work. Now I need to add a smooth transition between images. I tried transition/ animate in CSS but that has a weird effect - there is a blackness between images. I think the transition property needs to be added to JS.

**Current situation** - there is stark difference as images change suddenly
**Expectation** - I want images to ease in and out.

Any help in this direction is greatly appreciated!

P.S. -> copy-pasting code here for ease of use:

```js
let line = document.getElementById("line");

line.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  setNewImage(event.target.value);
});

function setNewImage(value){
  // console.log(value);
  let currentImage = document.getElementsByClassName("playing");
  let removedImage = currentImage[0].classList.remove("playing");
  let imageToAdd = "image"+value;
  // console.log(imageToAdd);
  
  let getElToAdd = document.getElementsByClassName(imageToAdd);
  
  // console.log(getElToAdd);
  
  let newEl = getElToAdd[0];
  
 newEl.classList.add("playing");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lavendar;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 380px;
  height: 280px;
/*   background-color: pink; */
}

.scrollbar {
/*   padding: 0 5px 5px 0; */
}
.scrollbar input {
  width: 380px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.image {
  width: 380px;
  height: 260px;
  display: none;
}

.playing {
  display: block;
}
.image1 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/260') no-repeat;
}

.image2 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/378/260') no-repeat;
}

.image3 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/259') no-repeat;
}

.image4 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/379/260') no-repeat;
}

.image5 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/383/260') no-repeat;
}

.image6 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/261') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <ul>
      <li><img class="playing image image1" /></li>
      <li><img class="image image2" /></li>
      <li ><img class="image image3" /></li>
      <li><img class="image image4" /></img></li>
      <li><img class="image image5" /></li>
      <li><img class="image image6"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollbar">
    <input id="line" type="range" min=1 max =6 />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `opacity` instead of `display` to be able to add transition, and make your element position absolute to have them above each other:

```js
let line = document.getElementById("line");

line.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  setNewImage(event.target.value);
});

function setNewImage(value) {
  // console.log(value);
  let currentImage = document.getElementsByClassName("playing");
  let removedImage = currentImage[0].classList.remove("playing");
  let imageToAdd = "image" + value;
  // console.log(imageToAdd);

  let getElToAdd = document.getElementsByClassName(imageToAdd);

  // console.log(getElToAdd);

  let newEl = getElToAdd[0];

  newEl.classList.add("playing");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lavendar;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 380px;
  height: 280px;
}


.scrollbar input {
  width: 380px;
}

ul {
 position:relative; /*make them relative to ul not li*/
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
/* added this*/
ul li .image {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
/**/
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.image {
  width: 380px;
  height: 260px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition:1s all;
}

.playing {
  opacity:1;
}

.image1 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/260') no-repeat;
}

.image2 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/378/260') no-repeat;
}

.image3 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/259') no-repeat;
}

.image4 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/379/260') no-repeat;
}

.image5 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/383/260') no-repeat;
}

.image6 {
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/380/261') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="playing image image1"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image image2"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image image3"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image image4"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image image5"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="image image6"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollbar">
    <input id="line" type="range" min=1 max=6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot Temani :). Just one thing, if I had many more images, and bigger in size - I would want the animation to be more easy looking - somewhat like, 1 image pixel by pixel transforms into another. How can I do that?

Comment: @novembersky well such thing is not something you can easily do with CSS, you need more complex code for this. What you can easily do it's fading, sliding, etc but to change pixel by pixel is more complex